# Sails.js error trying to edit and update function

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I'm trying to create edit function and update function using Sails.js but i get an error after i click on edit button.

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i++){ %>
    <tr>
    <td> <%= categories[i].id %> </td>
    <td> <%= categories[i].name %> </td>
    </tr>
    <a href="category/edit?id=<%= categories[i].id %>">Edit</a> //when click on this it should be appeared to edit page. but instead I got an error
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
    </html>
```

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqYD.png)

[this is my edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ALij.png)

[this is routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K2jR.png)

[this is the error that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI3EY.png)

I'm sorry to post it as pictures, i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple issues with your code.

If you are looking to return your edit page as a view. The following steps should work.

Firstly, remove all references of your /category/edit route from the routes config file.

Then alter the edit function in your CategoryController to respond with a view and pass the data from the findOne model method into the response. To this replace

```
res.redirect('/category');
```

with

```
res.view({ category : data });
```

Finally, change the category edit view to work with the data passed in the response.

```
action="/category/update/<%= category.id %>"
```

Any questions, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Now i can enter to edit pages, but when i click on submit button 
I got Sending 500 server error response : ReferenceError: id is not defined 
instead.

Comment: Now I got it!! Thank you!! but I still have more question, can you help me with that? i'm kinda stack here.

Comment: Are they sails.js related questions?

Comment: yes, they are. i'm stuck like 3 hrs, now. Still haven't manage to finish.

Comment: Have you opened them as a new question on stack overflow?